# LiveCode mobilePickPhoto- Can't load some images from library

Tags: mobile, photo, livecode

I can't seem to load some of the photos from the mobile library to the card using mobilePickPhoto "library".

```
set the lockloc of the templateimage to true    
set the width of the templateimage to "300"    
set the height of the templateimage to "400"    
set the left of the templateimage to "50"    
set the top of the templateimage to "10"    
mobilePickPhoto "library"    
if the result <> "cancel" then put the last image into image 1 of card 1
```

I'm not sure why but is it due to the size restrictions set? May I know how can I allow upload of any images with different sizes?

Really appreciate if anyone can help me out. Thanks.

Using LiveCode 6.7, testing on Sony Xperia (Android).

Comment: What exactly does "can't seem to load" mean? What exactly is happening? What is the value of `the result`, when the result isn't `Cancel`? Do the first 100 chars of the image indicate that a picture has been loaded or is the image completely empty? Is a new image control even created? Etc., etc., etc.,...

Comment: Sorry for not giving more details. The result I get is "error: could not get image data". E.g. 2 images of same size 1080x1920 in PNG format, one captured on 20141010 and one captured on 20140606. The photo from 20140606 could not be load and gives this error but the one from 20141010 is able to be displayed.

Comment: It could be a problem with Android. How many picture folders do you have? Are the two pictures in the same folders? You can see this with a file browser for Android or if you connect your device to a computer.

Comment: Yes, both the pictures are resided in /Pictures/Screenshots folder. I found that although that image could not be loaded when I open it from "Album" (from Xperia's photo library), but the same image can be loaded if I choose from "Images"->"Screenshots"... Like you said, it may be a problem with Android. Thanks for the help!